# Using where DeviceName -contains and getting no results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the content from the boot order list with the following command but `$pr` is empty and there is no error message:

```
 $pr = Get-HPBIOSUEFIBootOrder $conObj | select -Expand UEFIBootOrder |select -Expand DeviceName| Where DeviceName -contains "*Target:0, Lun:0)"^
```

Where's my mistake?

When I run this:

```
$pr = Get-HPBIOSUEFIBootOrder $conObj | select -Expand UEFIBootOrder |select -Expand DeviceName
```

It returns this:

```
Generic USB Boot
Embedded LOM 1 Port 1 : HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331i Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv6) 
Embedded LOM 1 Port 1 : HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331i Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv4) 
Slot 3 Port 1 : HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530T Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv6) 
Embedded RAID 1 : Smart Array P440ar Controller - 279.43 GiB, RAID 1 Logical Drive(Target:0, Lun:1)
Windows Boot Manager
Internal USB 1 : HPE Dual 8GB MicroSD EM USB Kit - USB RAID LUN
Embedded RAID 1 : Smart Array P440ar Controller - 279.37 GiB, RAID 1 Logical Drive(Target:0, Lun:0)
Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 1 : HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 533FLR-T Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv6) 
Embedded RAID 1 : Smart Array P440ar Controller - 279.37 GiB, RAID 1 Logical Drive(Target:0, Lun:2)
Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 1 : HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 533FLR-T Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv4) 
Slot 3 Port 1 : HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530T Adapter - NIC (PXE IPv4)
```

Comment: What does `Get-HPBIOSUEFIBootOrder $conObj | select -Expand UEFIBootOrder |select -Expand DeviceName` return?

Comment: I also assume `^` on the end of the line is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-like` instead of `-contains`.

Contains should be used when you want to determine if a value is in a collection of values. Like should be used (with wildcard characters) when you want to partially match a string. This is a common PowerShell misconception.

You've also used `-ExpandProperty` on DeviceName after which have a collection of strings without that property name. As such you need to do this in your `Where`:

```
| Where {$_ -like "*Target:0, Lun:0)"}
```

`$_` is a special placeholder that represents the current item in the pipeline, which with a system.string object is (by default) its string value.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bigger picture of my little project.
And what i´ve reached so far. 
It will find more makings in the near future.

```
##
# The following Script is checking the current HPPowerProfile Setting on the local Server
# and set it to Maximum_Performance if its not already set.
#
# Also it set´s the UEFIBootOrder to HDD firts (Target:0, Lun:0)
##


# Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\mysecurestring.txt
# Set Access Credentials

    $username = "*******"
    $password = cat C:\mysecurestring.txt | Convertto-SecureString
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

# Set ILO Hostname

    $sv = hostname 
    $ri = $sv.replace("YY","XX")

# Connect to HPBios

    $conObj = Connect-HPBIOS $ri -Credential $cred -DisableCertificateAuthentication

# Check current BootMode (depending on Boot Mode, other cmdlet´s will be executed)

    $bm = $conObj | Get-HPBIOSBootMode | select -Expand BootMode
        if ( $bm -eq "UEFI Mode")
            {echo "UEFI"}
        else 
            {echo "echo $bm"}

# Check current Server Power Profile

    $pr = Get-HPBIOSPowerProfile $conObj | select -Expand HPPowerProfile   
        if (-not( $pr -eq "Maximum Performance"))
            {$conObj | Set-HPBIOSPowerProfile -HPPowerProfile Maximum_Performance}
        else 
            {echo "No change needed"}

# Find HDD and move it to Boot Order #1

    $bo = Get-HPBIOSUEFIBootOrder $conObj | select -Expand UEFIBootOrder | Where DeviceName -like "*Drive(Target:0, Lun:0)" | select -Expand Index
        if (-not( $bo -eq "1"))
            {$conObj | Set-HPBIOSUEFIBootOrder -UEFIBootOrder "$bo,1"}
        else 
            {echo "No change needed"}
```